# Destructor not deleting allocated memory

Tags: c++, memory-management, destructor, new-operator, delete-operator

I have a class that includes a std::uint_8 pointer and the destructor should be called to delete the allocated memory. The issue I'm having is that a complier error occurs and states that the memory was not allocated, but I know I allocated it in my default constructor.
Here's my default constructor:

```
BigInteger::BigInteger() {
  unsigned char aArray [4];
  aArray[0] = 0;
  m_number = new unsigned char[4]
  m_number = aArray;
  m_digitCount = 0;
  m_sizeReserved = 4;
}
```

and here's my destructor:

```
BigInteger::~BigInteger() {
    delete [] m_number;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `m_number = aArray;` to do?

Comment: You allocate `m_number` with `new` but on the next line you re-assign it to the local array.

Comment: Which is not only a memory leak but is undefined behavior if you use `m_number` later

Comment: What do you mean also by "The issue I'm having is that a complier error occurs and states that the memory was not allocated" ? How do you see that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`unsigned char aArray [4]` here you create an array of 4 elements on the stack. These will go out of scope once the constructor has finished.

`m_number = new unsigned char[4]` now you create 4 elements on the heap. You allocate the memory and you'll be in charge of cleaning it up. Not an issue, you do so in the destructor.

`m_number = aArray;` now you change what `m_number` is pointing to, effectively losing a pointer to the memory you allocated. Now you have a leak.

Any use of `m_number` outside of this constructor is now undefined behaviour, because you're accessing memory you no longer own.

`delete [] m_number;` now you're deleting memory you don't own. UB.

Don't reassign `m_number` and you won't have these issues. Better yet, use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and watch as these manual memory management problems melt away.

Answer (score 1):

That line

```
m_number = aArray;
```

assigns a local variable's address to `m_number`.

That address cannot be used in conjunction with `delete [] m_number;`, the memory address allocated with `new unsigned char[4]` is overridden and lost after that assignment.

Answer (score 0):

You have a classical scenario of a **memory leak**. In essence what you are doing is the following:

1. Allocate memory (`m_number = new unsigned char[4]`)
2. Override the pointer that points to that allocated memory (`m_number = aArray`)
3. **Never** delete the allocated memory as you no longer know where it is - you have lost the pointer to it (it got overwritten)